# Recycularview adapter not set in tab fragment in MVP pattern, showing error no adapter attached skipping layout

Tags: android

> I am using MVP pattern to display employee list using tablayout in
>   recycular view i got error no adapter set code paste below, when i add
>   the list value and recycular adapter inside return view means it works
>   fine but if i goes separate interface method mean adapter not called

public class Employees extends Fragment implements GeneralView {

            View view;
            private EmployeePresenter employeePresenter;
            Response<ArrayPOJO> response;
            public RecyclerView recyclerView;
            public ArrayList<EmployeePojo> employeetList = new ArrayList<>();
            public EmployeeAdapter empAdapter;
            public EmployeePojo employeePojo;

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employee, container, false);

                Employees employees = new Employees();
                employeePresenter = new EmployeeDetailsImpl(employees);

                recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(empAdapter);

                empDetails();
                return view;
            }

            private void empDetails() {

                employeePresenter.employeeDetails();
            }



            @Override
            public void onSuccessResponseView(Response<POJO> response, String type) {

            }



            @Override
            public void onSuccessResponseArrayView(Response<ArrayPOJO> response, String type) {

                ArrayPOJO empPojoresp = response.body();

                List<POJO> arrayPOJO = empPojoresp.getDetails();

                for (POJO pojo : arrayPOJO) {
                    employeePojo = new EmployeePojo(pojo.getId(), pojo.getMobile(), pojo.getName(), pojo.getIMAGE());
                    employeetList.add(employeePojo);
                }

                recyclerView.setAdapter(new EmployeeAdapter(getActivity(), employeetList));


                empAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 Employees employees = new Employees();
 employeePresenter = new EmployeeDetailsImpl(employees);
```

Use

```
employeePresenter = new EmployeeDetailsImpl(this);
```

because Employees create one more object class

Answer (score 0):

Please change below code

```
 Employees employees = new Employees();
 employeePresenter = new EmployeeDetailsImpl(employees);
```

to

```
 employeePresenter = new EmployeeDetailsImpl(this);
```

because you are creating another instance for the same fragment